# gcloud beta functions deploy error from Travis. Source repository URL is invalid does not match the expected pattern

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, travis-ci, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

So [my .travis.yml](https://github.com/HarvsG/r-SpaceX-AI-Bot/blob/master/.travis.yml) build usually deploys happily. But after returning to the project after a few months I am finding that I am getting the below error. Looks at the gcloud [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy) seems to suggest other formats for source repository builds, but I have tried these and have gotten the same error. Please help!

I can manually trigger the build using the UI!

```
Restarting command:
  $ gcloud --quiet beta functions deploy SpaceXFulfillment --source-url https://source.developers.google.com/p/r-spacex-ai/r/r-SpaceX-AI-google-source-repo --source-path / --trigger-http
WARNING: The --source-url flag is deprecated; use --source instead.
WARNING: The --source-path flag is deprecated; use --source instead.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Bad Request], message=[The request has errors
Problems:
Source repository URL is invalid https://source.developers.google.com/p/r-spacex-ai/r/r-SpaceX-AI-google-source-repo/moveable-aliases/master// does not match the expected pattern
```

I have tried with several other formats!!

Environment details

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Node.js version: 6.9.1
- npm version: 3.10.8
- @google-cloud/functions-emulator version

  Google Cloud SDK 180.0.0
  bq 2.0.27
  core 2017.11.10
  gsutil 4.28

Steps to reproduce

1. https://travis-ci.org/HarvsG/r-SpaceX-AI-Bot/builds/304024024
2. interestingly if I manually fill in the repository box with the URL instead of just the repo name on the GUI build interface I get the same error. (It works if I just put the repo name).
   [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command if you have a mirror repository:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myFunction --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repos/$REPOSITORY_NAME/moveable-aliases/$BRANCH/paths// --trigger-http
```

`$PROJECT_ID` refers to your google cloud project id.
`$REPOSITORY_NAME` refers to your repository name.
`$BRANCH` refers to the branch you want to deploy from.

For your case the command would be:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy SpaceXFulfillment --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/r-spacex-ai/repos/r-SpaceX-AI-google-source-repo/moveable-aliases/master/paths// --trigger-http
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end this solved the problem.

Fixed by using the new command format as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy), although those docs are very confusing as I did not understand regex. So  I did the below changes. I have noticed it is `/moveable-aliases/` for branches and `/fixed-aliases/` for tag. So I made the below change to my .travis.yml file.

`-      - gcloud --quiet beta functions deploy SpaceXFulfillment --source-url https://source.developers.google.com/p/r-spacex-ai/r/r-SpaceX-AI-google-source-repo --source-path / --source-branch master --trigger-http
+      - gcloud --quiet beta functions deploy SpaceXFulfillment --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/r-spacex-ai/repos/r-SpaceX-AI-google-source-repo/moveable-aliases/master --trigger-http`

[Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/164) to original github issue describing the issue.